# How do I send pointerReleased to event to leftMenu button?

Tags: codenameone

I want to send a click event to the left menu button to show the main menu.

How do I get the left menu button (with a red circle in the graph) to show the menu by the codes below?

It shows the main menu but after b1(another button) is pressed.

```
getToolbar().getLeftSideMenuButton().pointerPressed(getToolbar().getLeftSideMenuButton().getAbsoulteX(),getToolbar().getLeftSideMenuButton().getAbsoluteY());
getToolbar().getLeftSideMenuButton().pointerReleased(getToolbar().getLeftSideMenuButton().getAbsoulteX(),getToolbar().getLeftSideMenuButton().getAbsoluteY());
b1.pointerPressed(b1.getAbsoulteX(), b1.getAbsoluteY());
b1.pointerReleased(b1.getAbsoulteX(), b1.getAbsoluteY());
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working, but if you want to open the side menu why not just invoke `getToolbar()..openSideMenu()`? Also use `press()` and `release()` instead of `pointerPressed` etc.